# CakePHP - Additional field on Model to display list of roles

Tags: php, cakephp, model, cakephp-acl

I need a field in a model (specifically, it is a "User" model), that will list me all the Roles (ARO) as a delimited string (e.g. "Admin, Officer"). However, that field would be a read-only field, which could be used directly on the view.

This is what i have now:

```
["id"]=>  "1" 
["username"]=> "matt@ruler.us" 
["password"]=> "d1266f045175f0863dfe26d8bdfd9f91f4ca53bb" 
["role_id"]=> "0"
```

The role_id refers to a ARO role. I would like to have a read-only, view specific field to contain the list of roles.

How to do this properly?

Comment: Do you have another table "roles"? If so, and your relationships are setup correctly, when you select the role in the view, the roles available should show up in a select tag.

Comment: That's a good point. However there is not a classic Role table with a clean relational design, but instead the role-user associations are stored in a key-value fashion in the ARO table